provided configuration file been delete and not considered on nginx container start-up
i am trying to enable gzip compresssion on nginx container where my angular app in deployed, but for i unknown reason the configuration file i am providing on image build is not been considered when the container start-up
considering that this is my Dockerfile and default.conf file :
FROM nginx:alpine3.18

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

COPY dist/prod-web/browser/ /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY default.conf  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/html text/xml text/plain text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml+rss application/xml application/javascript application/xhtml+xml application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/json image/svg+xml image/svg+xml image/x-icon application/rss+xml application/atom_xml;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on; 
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_min_length 100;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

so normally i expect the default.conf file should be the only one in the conf.d folder, but instead  i have two file there prod-web.conf
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
default                    off;
text/html                  epoch;
text/css                   max;
application/json           max;
application/javascript     max;
~image/                    max;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
    expires $expires;
    gzip  on;
    #error_page  404              /404.html;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    #location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
    #    try_files $uri =404;
    #}
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}

and proxy.conf
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;

do anyone know the reason i am having this ?

Is there a mounted volume on your nginx container (which could erase your default.conf) ? If not, maybe try another image tag (without alpine for examples). You can also try to mount your conf file in a volume like :
-v ./myconf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
Does another process interact with the nginx container? Like certbot?

thanks, to put me on the way, there was a mounted cm in the /etc/nginx/conf.d/ folder
